# How do I identify the key of this modulation?

Tags: theory, sheet-music, modulation

I have been doing practice exams and having trouble with modulation. This was the modulation question.

[image]

Am I correct? If not, what did I do wrong and how should I do it? Thank you.

Comment: Doesn’t it tell you if you’re right or wrong?

Comment: @iMerchant not on practice exams, unfortunately.

Comment: I think that E# leads to F#minor on the first line

Comment: @Shevliaskovic - it could equally lead to F# or F#m. As E# is the leading note for both.

Comment: The question is based on a very "19th-century" style of music theory. To be honest, I wouldn't consider that the example modulates from B minor at all. There are a couple of secondary dominants, and the final II-V-I cadence changes the II to a Neapolitan chord, but most people wouldn't call those "modulations" any more.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid I have to give my opinion that you've got them both wrong.

I think it's pretty clear where we get to at the end of the first line.  That E# is a strong clue. (And we can remind our 'jazz harmony' collegues that a 'chromatic mediant relationship' is nothing new.)   The second line is less clear.  I don't think there's a anything worth calling a modulation at all, though both E minor (that D# is the clue) and C major are visited.

I can't see where you got D major from, but if it did occur I suggest you call it the 'relative major' rather than 'relative key'.

Ideally, you would now take my reply and any other constructive replies you get to your teacher and discuss whether he agrees, and why.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the first answer, the first mod is to either F# or F#m, then, as Laurence states, there is hardly a mod to either C or Am, so I guess those are answers which could do. Seems a bit vague to me. Whether that's the intent, don't know. Some exam questions are either written like that, or just not well written!

Comment: I've found that the AMEB is a rather obscure examination board, so what you've said makes sense. Unfortunately, I can't change that! Thanks very much anyway!

Comment: I love the way you get more upvotes for saying 'I agree with Laurence' than I got for the answer!

Comment: Be fair! I gave you a good one a couple of weeks ago! Returned favour?

Answer (score -2):

1. B minor (F# C# A#)
2. F# minor (F# C# G# E#), A#(non-chord note)
3. E minor (F#, C natural, D#)
4. B minor (F# C# A#)

I am a new learner. As I want to recognize the key and a modulation, I am happy to find this exercise. Thank you.

Comment: Hi may. Can you please articulate why you have chosen these answers. Otherwise they are not of any value to future visitors, and you are likely to just get more downvotes.